# How can I send file using parameter instead set it in FilePath in JMeter HTTP Request Sampler?

Tags: jmeter, http-post, jmeter-plugins

When I use bean shell script to preload the file to a variable and then
set it in parameter of HTTP request sampler to upload file, from the wireshark packets I find that the content-length is not right.
Also the content-type is set to text/plain which cause problem.
How can I change it?

Below are some pictures to show the jemter setup and wireshrak snoops.

[The wireshark snoop when the content of the file set as the value of the parameter of the Http request sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQWeq.png)
[The jmeter test element setup showing that the the content of the file is set in the http request parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkgU9.png)

Answer (score 1):

You're using wrong configuration:

1. Check `Use multipart/form-data for POST` box
2. Remove your file from `Parameters` area
3. Add it to `Send Files With the Request` area like:

   - File Path: `${__property(FileData,,)}`
   - Parameter Name: `File`
   - MIME Type: `text/plain`

     [image: Example upload configuration]

See [Performance testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) guide for more information on simulating file upload and download events in your JMeter script.

Comment: The reason I need to preload the file content to a string is that I don't want to load file from the disk in every upload request because it takes time to load 2M file. So I load the file in my bean shell script in my setup thread group and try to use it in send parameters as I think 'the send files' section only allow me to provide file path. Any idea about how to implement file preloading?

Comment: My bean shell script looks this: import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

String filePath = vars.get("uploadFilePath");
print("filePath:" + filePath);
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filePath);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
for (int i; (i = in.read(buffer)) != -1; ) {
    bos.write(buffer, 0, i);
}
in.close();
byte[] fileData = bos.toByteArray();
print("length of file:" + fileData.length);
bos.close();
props.put("fileData", new String(fileData));

Comment: Following this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101904/how-to-send-byte-array-in-http-request-in-jmeter, is it possible to implement upload preloded file using http raw request?

Comment: I didn't ask "why do you need this", I pointed to wrong configuration of your HTTP Request sampler

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something in the above link, it says " if you add a Beanshell Pre Processor to your HTTP Request which performs file upload with something like:

FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("/home/glinius/401.png");
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
for (int i; (i = in.read(buffer)) != -1; ) {
    bos.write(buffer, 0, i);
}
in.close();
byte[] imageData = bos.toByteArray();
bos.close();
vars.put("imageData", new String(imageData));
You'll be able to add ${imageData} parameter in your POST request.