# Binary data in body is corrupted when sending HTTP POST in JMeter

Tags: http, encoding, jmeter, beanshell, jmeter-5.0

I have a local web app with an HTTP POST endpoint.
This endpoint receives emails sent from SendGrid.

I have saved the body of a previous email with attachments which I know works, as requestBody.bin.

I'm trying to replicate this HTTP POST request using JMeter.

I have this Beanshell Preprocessor script:

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\Projects\\centaurjmeter\\src\\InboundEmails\\requestBody.bin");
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[999024]; //Value of Content-Length from when I sent the actual email. So this should be more than enough just for the HTTP POST body.
for (int i; (i = in.read(buffer)) != -1; ) {
    bos.write(buffer, 0, i);
}
in.close();
byte[] requestBody = bos.toByteArray();
bos.close();

vars.put("requestBody", new String(requestBody, "ISO-8859-1"));
```

and I'm using `${requestBody}` in the body of the HTTP POST request:

This is what my JMeter test looks like:

[image]

In my HTTP POST action method, I'm saving the attachments of the email to file.

The pdfs seem to be slightly corrupted, only part of the text on each page is showing.
The .png files do not even open.

I've tried using:

```
vars.put("requestBody", new String(requestBody));
vars.put("requestBody", new String(requestBody, "Windows-1252")); //ANSI
vars.put("requestBody", new String(requestBody, "ISO-8859-1")); //default encoding
```

But none of them work. "ISO-8859-1" results in the least amount of corruption, in that at least some text appears in the pdfs (but the .png files don't work at all).

I can't use a HTTP Raw Request Sampler because that doesn't work with https.

How can I get the bytes from requestBody.bin and send them in my HTTP POST body correctly?

**UPDATE**

I read https://stackoverflow.com/a/41892324/2063755 and tried sending requestBody.bin as a file with the request in the "Files Upload" tab, but I get the same result as using the Beanshell Preprocessor script.

**UPDATE**

The above link actually did help me solve the problem.
I just had to add this extra `TE` header:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that the same encoding is being applied everywhere, I would recommend sticking to [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

1. Run JMeter providing [`file.encoding=UTF-8` property](https://www.baeldung.com/java-char-encoding), it can be added to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting so you can use the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) directly in the "Body Data" tab of your HTTP Request sampler:

   ```
   ${__groovy(new File('C:\\Projects\\centaurjmeter\\src\\InboundEmails\\requestBody.bin').getText('UTF-8'),)}
   ```

   More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)
3. Assuming everything goes well your "local web app" should see the identical file, it can be double-checked using a 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). Make sure to use UTF-8 for parsing the file in your app as well.

Comment: Hi Dmitri T, thanks for your answer.
What do you mean use UTF-8 to parse the file? The requestBody.bin contains the HTTP POST body which has multipart/form-data content type. The attachments are then read when received by the web app and saved to blob storage using:
var emailDataProvider = new InboundEmailMultipartStreamProvider(_storageConfig, hasInvalidSize);
await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(emailDataProvider);

Are you saying I need to specify UTF-8 when saving the attachments?

Comment: I'm getting this error:
`Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script4.groovy: 1: Missing ')' @ line 1, column 10.
   new File('C:\Projects\centaurjmeter\src\InboundEmails\requestBody.bin').getText('UTF-8')`
I've made sure I used your line of code exactly as it is.

Comment: Weird, changing it to `${__groovy(new File('C:/Projects/centaurjmeter/src/InboundEmails/requestBody.bin').getText('UTF-8'),)}` fixed it.

Comment: UTF-8 didn't work. I tried Windows-1252 (ANSI) since Notepad shows ANSI when I view the requestBody.bin file, but it didn't work either (both just show blank pdfs). I then tried ISO-8859-1 which is apparently the default encoding in HTTP and it created a pdf with some visible text, but the .png files were corrupt.

Comment: I don't think UTF-8 would work since it's binary data. The reason is that UTF-8 expects a certain combination of bits. For example the first two bits of the 2nd, 3rd and 4th bytes have to be "10", so "01" etc would be invalid UTF-8.